# css3 animation with bounce at the end

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to get a css3 animation to work but it's not working as expected. I'm essentially after a really quick close with a bounce at the end, like elastic. I just can't get the animation to close quick enough and the bounce looks really slow.

I have created a fiddle. Any help is appreciated.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/DZ8Qv/

Comment: Why don't you use http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/? They have two functions 'easeInBack' and 'easeOutBack' which give you the bounce you're looking for.

Comment: *bounce looks slow*? Have you tried decreasing the animation duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at cubic-bezier easing, which can do the bouncing effect you want. Lea Verou built a great tool for creating them at http://cubic-bezier.com/

For example, here's one with a bounce, but you can play with it to get the effect you want: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.91,.8,.54,1.39

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not enabled transitions because you use the wrong name in the `#drawer` css rule

Instead of

```
-webkit-transform: all 0.1s;
```

you must use

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/DZ8Qv/2/

Answer (score -3):

Use jquery for this they have several plugins to help with this easing is one of them they have easeoutbounce and such like and you can change the speeds and or animation effects very easy to implement too.